sample size in chi-squared test
The chi-square test of independence is a type of non-parametric test, but in cases of small sample sizes, the Fisher's exact test should be used instead. My understanding of non-parametric methods is that they do not assume a specific distribution. So, why then impose sample size restrictions if the method does not assume distribution?

From what I understand, the Chi-squared is often called non-parametric because it does not assume any distribution on your sample.
However, the test-statistic itself is said to follow (approximately) a chi-square distribution (so this is not about your sample anymore and hence it is viewed as non-parametric). But here comes the sample size in play: since you work with categories, this chi-square approximation is not very good if your cell frequencies are very low ('very low' has then been determined to be 5, but as always in statistics, don't stick to thresholds to much in my opinion). Due to these categories, often a continuity correction is also at play as well for reasonably small sample sizes.
So it is to make sure the test-statistic approximation with the chi-square distribution is valid, not the sample approximation to a normal distribution.
Edit: As Nick pointed out, this is indeed with respect to expected cell frequencies! Also, 5 is an often used threshold, but more importantly, they should be above 1, which sometimes is already enough for a good approximations. Some text books have mixed guidelines, for example 80% expected frequencies should be above 5 and 20% above 1. When in doubt, as always in statistics, do a small sensitivity analysis or compare it with results of another method (e.g. Fisher exact test maybe for small samples!)

To simplify but perhaps also to clarify a tangled issue: The major issue is whether expected frequencies are too low for the approximation to work well, not observed frequencies as might be inferred from this (and which you may or may not be implying). I agree with the general tenor of not treating thresholds slavishly but add that expected frequencies all being above about $1$ seems good enough in much practice, and is a guideline in various texts. However, if in doubt try some sensitivity analysis or another method.

Yes, very good point I forgot to emphasize, this is indeed with respect to the expected frequencies, will add it!

Thank you for your response. I think I understand the first question now—there is no assumption about the form of the population distribution, but the test statistic must follow a chi-square distribution. But why is this? It sounds similar to the idea of the Central Limit Theorem (regardless of the population distribution, as the sample size increases, the distribution of the test statistic approaches a normal distribution with smaller variance).

Yes, the central limit theorem is certainly involved! Maybe this tread (which involves more mathematics) can help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499957/why-does-the-chi-squared-test-statistic-follow-the-chi-squared-distribution

The first paragraph of this Wikipedia is a good summary.
"Parametric statistics is a branch of statistics which leverages models based on a fixed (finite) set of parameters.[1] Conversely nonparametric statistics does not assume explicit (finite-parametric) mathematical forms for distributions when modeling data. However, it may make some assumptions about that distribution, such as continuity or symmetry, or even an explicit mathematical shape but have a model for a distributional parameter that is not itself finite-parametric."

As Mathemagician777 explained in a different answer, the size restriction is due to an approximation made for the distribution of the test statistic.
It should be noted, however, that this restriction nowadays is no longer necessary, if you have access to a computer. You can thus use the same test statistic and simulate its distribution under the null hypothesis with a Monte Carlo test. Actually, this is readily implemented in the R function chisq.test: Just use the option simulate.p.value=TRUE.
For the general theory with an arbitrary test statistic and an arbitrary distribution under the null hypothesis, see, e.g.

Jöckel: "Finite Sample Properties and Asymptotic Efficiency of Monte Carlo Tests." Ann. Statist. 14(1): 336-347 (March, 1986)

